# What's the difference between "sensus plenior" and "inspired sensus plenior"?

Tags: hermeneutical-approaches, sensus-plenior

What's the difference between "*sensus plenior*" and "inspired *sensus plenior*"?

Are the terms interchangeable? If "the deeper meaning intended by God but not intended by the human author" ([*sensus plenior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensus_plenior)) exists wouldn't it be inspired?

Comment: I hope you answer this yourself, because you are the one I would go to for the answer!!

Comment: @jonI think you added a semantic question. Of course if God intended it, it is inspired.  But in the context of Evangelical discussions, it is more than a semantic issue. Ichthydion did a great job with it.

Comment: @Richard Here is the first text I now use to teach children to read sensus plenior. It shows that he source of symbol is derived from the Hebrew letters and words themselves. You can see it applied in the dietary law.  https://sensusplenior.net/wiki/Pneumnemonic_Hebrew_for_Beginners   AND https://sensusplenior.net/wiki/The_Dietary_Law

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=%E2%80%9Cinspired%20sensus%20plenior%22), I find that "inspired *sensus plenior*" is most closely associated with [Robert L. Thomas](http://zondervan.com/thomasrl) out of The Master's Seminary.  More accurately, he coined the term "inspired *sensus plenior* applications (ISPA)" to describe a subset of the hermeneutical principles used by New Testament authors:

> When interpreting the OT and NT, each in light of the single, grammatical-historical meaning of a passage, two kinds of NT uses of the OT surface, one in
>   which the NT writer observes the grammatical-historical sense of the OT passage
>   and the other in which the NT writer goes beyond the grammatical-historical sense
>   in his use of an OT passage.  Inspired *sensus plenior* application (ISPA) designates
>   the latter usage.  Numerous passages illustrate each type of NT use of the OT.  The
>   ISPA type of usage does not grant contemporary interpreters the right to copy the
>   methodology of NT writers, nor does it violate the principle of single meaning.  The
>   ISPA meaning  of  the OT passage did not exist for man until the time of the NT
>   citation, being occasioned by Israel’s rejection of her Messiah at His first advent.
>   The ISPA approach approximates that advocated by Walton more closely than other
>   explanations of the NT use of the OT.  “Fulfillment”  terminology in the NT is
>   appropriate only for events that literally fulfil events predicted in the OT.—Robert L. Thomas, “The New Testament Use of the Old Testament,” *The Master’s Seminary Journal (TMSJ)* Volume 13, No. 1 (Spring 2002): 80.[[PDF](http://www.tms.edu/tmsj/tmsj13d.pdf)]

The term does not seem to have acquired much traction (though it's not been around very long in terms of Biblical scholarship), however.  Perhaps part of the reason is that other thinkers do not feel the same need to separate the methods the apostles used from the methodology that is legitimate for modern exegetes.  Richard Barcellos of the Midwest Center for Theological Studies [notes](http://www.mctsowensboro.org/mcts-blog-original/nt-use-of-the-ot-part-ii-should-we-employ-the-hermeneutical-method-of-the-nt-no-part-2/):

> [Thomas] assumes a very limiting view of hermeneutics. He says that grammatical-historical hermeneutics consists of “[i]nterpret[ing] each statement in light of the principles of grammar and the facts of history. Take each statement in its plain sense if it matches common sense, and do not look for another sense.”  One wonders who gets to determine what constitutes “common sense” and if Jesus and his apostles would agree. Thomas’ view of grammatical-historical hermeneutics comes, in part, as a result of his commitment to what he calls the principle of single meaning.  He sees the New Testament adhering to this principle sometimes, but abandoning it at others.

To put it another way, if we abandon the suspect notion that the only legitimate meaning of a passage is its "single, grammatical-historical meaning", there's no particular reason to cordon off *sensus plenior* into categories of "inspired" and not.  Certainly it seems strange to hold the New Testament writers to the principles of the grammatical-historical method considering it has [only recently](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biblical_hermeneutics#Christian_biblical_hermeneutics) come into fashion.  Even that pillar of the Enlightenment, Isaac Newton, assumed there were [hidden meanings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaac_Newton%27s_religious_views#The_Bible) to be found in the Bible.

---

Now we still have the problem in that if we don't hold the New Testament writers (or anyone else) to the grammatical-historical meaning, how can we avoid interpretations of the  "fuller meaning" (i.e., *sensus plenior*) from being anything and everything the exegete wishes it to be?  How can we allow the early Christian writers to arrive at their interpretations without simultaneously giving license for [interpretations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaac_Newton%27s_religious_views#The_End_of_the_World) that indicate the world will end in 2060 AD?

One possible answer, appropriate in a Christian context, is the [Christological Hermeneutic](http://www.religion-online.org/showarticle.asp?title=0) which finds Jesus at the center of all of God's plans.  According to this reading of the Biblical texts, all divine revelation prior to Jesus was pointed toward the coming Messiah who would reconcile the broken world to God.  Therefore, we should expect certain texts to include meanings beyond the immediate meaning the human authors had in mind.  This is the principle Paul used when he [applied](http://www.esvbible.org/Galatians+4/) Genesis 3:15 to Jesus:

> ```
> I will put enmity between you and the woman,
>     and between your offspring and her offspring;
> he shall bruise your head,
>     and you shall bruise his heel.
> ```
>
> —Genesis 3:15 ([ESV](http://www.esvbible.org/Genesis+3/))

The historical-grammatical meaning of the text seems to be a sort of [just-so story](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-so_story).  Working inductively from the text, the Christological interpretation seems strained to the point of breaking, but working deductively from the claims of Jesus of Nazareth, the interpretation is more than plausible.  Considering it is a forward-looking statement from God concerning the fallout from sin, it's not surprising that Paul (and other Christians) would see the Christ sent to redeem the world in this text in addition to other meanings.

### Conclusion

Dividing *sensus plenior* into "inspired" and "plain" flavors seems to be a solution to the problem of how early Christians were able to arrive at "non-literal" meanings of passages from the Tanakh without giving license to modern interpretations that eschew the historical-grammatical method.

Answer (score 6):

"Sensus plenior" is used to speak of the higher meaning contained in scripture without regard to the arguments concerning who may or may not discern it.

Those committed to the literal-historical methodology use the term "Inspired Sensus Plenior" to affirm that the apostles recognized a fuller meaning in the Old Testament without endorsing a modern use of methods to interpret it. "Inspired" is used to say that because the apostles were apostles, only they were authorized to interpret the scriptures in a non-literal-historical method.  Whenever confronted with a hermeneutical problem caused by the literal-historical method, they can claim "inspiration". <sup>1</sup>

This argument is similar to Mormon claim for the Book of Mormon. There are no golden plates to examine so we must simply believe the word of Joseph and his witnesseswhen the translation has no basis.  In the case of "Inspired Sensus Plenior", the literal-historical method is incapable of reproducing the methods of the NT authors, and so we must simply believe that their special revelation is true.

This is contrary to the evidence of the scriptures themselves. Jesus showed the disciples on the road to Emmaus all the scriptures that spoke of him. As the apostles preached, those who wished could verify what they said against the OT as the Bereans did.

<sup>1</sup> <sub>*THE NEW TESTAMENT USE OF THE OLD TESTAMENT* -- Robert L. Thomas</sub>

Comment: However, we are not told the details of the conversation on the road to Emmaus, and to assume or insert one's own assumptions seems questionable.  How do you know that he didn't exegete Isaiah 53 to them, for example?

Comment: Since those using the term "Inspired Sensus Plenior" concede that sensus plenior exists and the apostles were authorized to exegete it there is no reason to assume special revelation since the text says he showed them. "27  And beginning at Moses and all the prophets, he expounded unto them in all the scriptures the things concerning himself."  ... Not just Isaiah 53.

Comment: It was Jesus speaking at that point, not one of the disciples.  And the author of the paper you linked seems to be making the point that the authors of scripture were only permitted by God to use whatever sensus plenior He had previously placed there.  In other words, it still doesn't imply that *every* passage has dual meaning or that there are other senses still waiting to be discovered.  See his statement on page 9:  "Since hermeneutics is a human discipline, gleaning that
second sense is an impossibility in an examination of the OT source of the citation."

Comment: And on page 10, "Johnson goes a step further and advocates that modern interpreters reproduce the exegetical methodology of the NT writers in their handling of the OT. That means going beyond the literal meaning of the OT to discover sensus plenior meanings of OT passages in addition to the ones divulged in the NT. That is another distinction between his approach and the ISPA approach which would emphasize the unique prerogative of NT writers to employ charismatic exegesis, and would insist that no one today possesses that same prophetic gift."

Comment: Hmm..  So in re-reading your post and comments, this seems to be precisely what you're saying - that, unlike the ISPA stance that the NT authors were uniquely equipped to find sensus plenior, you believe that it is still possible to do so.  However, you're going to need a different example than post-resurrection Jesus, then.

Comment: The point I made was that Jesus showed the apostles how to interpret sensus plenior, and therefor they did not need special revelation to do so. Post ressurection Jesus is the one who showed them. "Jesus showed the disciples on the road to Emmaus all the scriptures that spoke of him" says nothing of the scope of 'all' other than 'all of the relevant scriptures which speak of Jesus'. The claim that all scriptures speak of Jesus is a different discussion.

Comment: And that's now back to my previous statement - you're inserting into the text your own assumption.  Since we don't know the actual contents of the discussion, you're reading "Jesus showed the apostles how to interpret sensus plenior" into it.

Comment: The language of sensus plenior is childish riddle. When you 'get' a riddle, you then know how to solve it in the future and others like it. Since Jesus showed them all the pictures of himself from Genesis through the prophets, they 'got it'.

Comment: Because Moses also talked directly (plainly) about the Messiah, as did many other authors.  Yes, some passages did have dual meaning in that they talked about "current" events and also could apply to the Messiah.  (See Psalm 22)  However, Jesus made that direct link in His quotation from the cross.

Comment: And the pashat never loses it's meaning. But there were things in the scripture which were not plain to them, which he showed them.

Comment: The question is resolved when the methods of sensus plenior are shown to resolve the 'odd' usages that the literal-historisists list. And when children unpack the sensus plenior on their own.

Comment: Allow me to restate for emphasis:  "there were things in the scripture which were not plain to them, which he showed them" - you *do not know* the specifics of what He said.  Therefore, you can't use this passage as a warrant for sensus plenior.  Plus, you're arguing *up* the authority tree, not *down* it.  It would be better for your argument if you could identify a non-apostle, who was not Jesus, who uses sensus plenior.

Comment: We specifically know he showed them scriptures that spoke of him, which were not available in plain reading.  This is the definition of sensus plenior. So he showed them sensus plenior. The evidence is, agreed by those claiming 'inspired sensus plenior' that those passages exist. It is also agreed, that they used sensus plenior in their odd usage. We can now see that they taught is how to do it in the gospels. This is another conversation. Also, if we follow the methods they teach, even children can unpack undocumented portions. Non-apostles who are not Jesus. Gotta run.

Comment: Having read up some more on this subject, I think you're focusing on only one camp within the larger literal-historical hermeneutic (the "single-meaning" principle) as representative of the entire hermenutic.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1740/discussion-between-bob-jones-and-galacticcowboy)

Comment: Wouldn't it be obvious that sensus plenior' would be natural post resurrection, especially for Jesus, but also for His followers, including present day followers?  The fact that the actual revelation of the historical Jesus, His life, his crucifixion, his resurrection, His assencion, His life in Heaven at present, and basically all the New Testament inspired expression - would express and expose these truths once hidden but now revealed?  If our understanding of the coming Messiah was him to become King, and He was killed, the eyes of our understanding wouldn't allow us to see the whole truth.

Comment: Once the facts / truths are revealed, it would be normative to see them throughout scripture because they are no longer hidden, in effect, due to expressed revelation.

Comment: @JLB One would think that once a hidden meaning is revealed truly, that it would be obvious to those who spoke and thought like Hebrews. Unfortunately, we mostly think like Greeks. The Hebrew hermeneutic was pushed out of the church by Augustine who said the Greek Septuagint was more reliable than the original Hebrew. It is no surprise for it to receive disdain from those who received their hermeneutic from Augustine.

Answer (score 4):

Whether *sensus plenior* (either inspired or not) exists is largely a question that depends on the particular doctrine an interpretation is evaluated in.  Certainly the early Christian writers believed that the Hebrew Scriptures they inherited contained important links with the man they had come to revere as the Messiah.  There's no particular reason why they wouldn't continue to use [all the tools of interpretation](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/2923/68) available in the culture they were active in.

Among the Dead Sea Scrolls, we find examples of an interpretative technique call [*Pesher*](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/55/68), which re-interpreted the Tanakh in light of current events.  There's no particular reason to suppose that early Christian authors, most of whom were Jews, would not try their hand at the same technique.  In fact, we know that Jesus himself interpreted the prophesy in Daniel 7 as a being fulfilled [in himself](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Son_of_man#Christianity).  So it's no particular surprise that his followers would not discover hints of Jesus' life in the Tanakh as well.

### Conclusion

God only knows whether or not any particular interpretation is inspired.  Certainly the authors of the New Testament *believed* they were discovering deeper meaning in Scripture.  However, there's no particular need for us to follow their precise techniques since those methods are not commonly used in our culture.

Comment: +1 but you have used the word 'particular' 5 times!

Comment: @JackDouglas: I suppose I need to [edit] this particular answer as I'm particular about avoiding using particular words too often!  ;-)

Comment: Well I don't particularly mind if you want it left just the way it is :) tbh I was wondering if it was deliberate irony given the question ;)